# Utilities for firewalled downloads

Tags: linux, security, download-manager, firewall

I am looking for a linux utility that downloads a file and set a firewall that restricts all connection to only the server that is transferring the file.

I would set it in bash if it doesn't really exist yet.

Comment: Do you want the only permissible connection to be to the file? Is the file always from the same location (ie. same HTTP / FTP address?)

Comment: The firewalled downloader should adapt on case there are multiple UPs involved. One possibility is to work with curl or whet source code but I am sure people have already build that